# Node 1(ntp-check) status: error

Tags: puppet, openstack

I was trying to install openstack using Mirantis. I successfully installed and configured Mirantis. I created 2 nodes and when I click "deploy" option it started deploying. When it is nearing to 100%, am getting this error in Astute logs.

Node 1(ntp-check) status: error puppet

Someone please help to fix this.

Comment: Did you change to local ntp server?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed this issue. As my machine running behind office firewall. So, I couldn't access the ntp server URLs. After, the admin team provided access to those URLs and it is fixed.